# dividing a number into other significant digits

Tags: java, currency

The title is quite confusing, as i am not aware what to title this question. Anyway I have java programming homework that requires a number to be divide into the correct amount of change. I am not getting any message when using the program, i can input the number, then nothing happens.

Thanks

-Jordan

```
double input;   // The input
double l = 0;   // Toonies (2.00 dollars)
double t = 0;   // loonies (1.00 dollars)
double q = 0;   // quarters (0.25 dollars)
double d = 0;   // dimes (0.10 dollars)
double n = 0;   // nickels (0.05 dollars)
double p = 0;   // pennies (0.01 dollars)

System.out.println("Hello, this application will tell you how much"
        + "change you have, based on your input.");
System.out.println("Please enter a real integer");
input = TextIO.getDouble();     // Retrieves the next double entered

while (input > 2) {
    t++;
} // Closes of toonie statement

while (input > 1) {
    l++;
} // Closes of loonie statement

while (input > 0.25) {
    q++;
} // Closes of quarter statement

while (input > 0.1) {
    d++;
} // Closes of dime statement

while (input > 0.05) {
    n++;
} // Closes of nickel statement

while (input > 0.01) {
    p++;
} // Closes of penny statement

System.out.println("You have "  // Prints a message saying how many of each coin you have
        + t + "toonies, "
+ l + "loonie(s), "
+ q + "quarter(s), "
+ d + "toonie(s), "
+ n + "toonies(s), "
+ p + "pennies(s), ");
```

Comment: All may be infinite loop.

Comment: If input is larger than any of the while loop requirements it will go into infinite loop, you need to reduce the input by the amount you increase the change.

Comment: Sidenote, you should look at `System.out.printf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each of those while loops, you also need to be subtracting the amount from the input. Since you are not, it probably is going into an infinite loop on one of those. For example:

```
while (input > 2) {
    t++;
    input -= 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not decrementing the input so you get stuck in an infinite loop in the first `while` for which the initial condition is true:

You should decrement the `input` amount in your loops:

```
while (input > 2) {
    t++;
    input -=2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable 'input' is never reduced, so once one of the while loops is entered, there's no way to exit it, and it will continue until you stop the program by some other means.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do you calculations in cents. This way you can use a long.  Instead of using a loop, you can just use integer division. This will be faster, shorter and more accurate.